# Self join a table to get values for all combinations of 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I have a table which has three columns **id**, **time_stamp**, **vm_name**, **cpu_usage**.

The table doesnt have values for all vm_names for every timestamp.

But I want a results which contains values for every vm_name for every time_stamp.

My table has 4 unique VMs and 20 unique timestamps.
     and the table contains 50 rows.

I want 4 X 20 = 80 rows to be returned and if a combination of vm_name and time_stamp is not already  present, it would assign a 0 value to the cpu usage.

The attempt below returns 162 rows where I dont see any null value for the cpuusage value not present.

```
select t1.timestamp,t2.timestamp,t1.vm_name,t2.vm_name,t1.cpuUsage, t2.cpuUsage from       `VM_monitoring_5min t1` 
right join VM_monitoring_5min t2
on t1.timestamp  = t2.timestamp
```

Here is the SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/998e0/1

Comment: can you provide sample table in fiddle? that may help others to know easily.

Comment: Add `distinct` to your `select` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct n.vm_name
          , c.timestamp
          , coalesce(t1.cpuUsage,0) 
       from VM_monitoring_5min n 
       join VM_monitoring_5min c 
       left 
       join VM_monitoring_5min t1
         On t1.vm_name = n.vm_name 
        and t1.timestamp = c.timestamp
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/998e0/3

Answer (score 0):

Cross join all distinct vm_name and timestamp, then left join your table.

```
select n.vm_name,c.timestamp,coalesce(t1.cpuUsage,0) 
from 
    (select distinct vm_name from VM_monitoring_5min) as n
    cross join
    (select distinct timestamp from VM_monitoring_5min) as c
    left join
    VM_monitoring_5min t1
    on n.vm_name = t1.vm_name and c.timestamp = t1.timestamp
;
```

Test [Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/998e0/2).